# How can I memoize a method that may return true, false, or nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, null, memoization

Obviously `||=` won't work

```
def x?
  @x_query ||= expensive_way_to_calculate_x
end
```

because if it turns out to be `false` or `nil`, then `expensive_way_to_calculate_x` will get run over and over.

Currently the best way I know is to put the value into an `Array`:

```
def x?
  return @x_query.first if @x_query.is_a?(Array)
  @x_query = [expensive_way_to_calculate_x]
  @x_query.first
end
```

Is there a more conventional or efficient way of doing this?

**UPDATE** I realized that I wanted to memoize `nil` in addition to `false` - this goes all the way back to https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1830-railscachefetch-does-not-work-with-false-boolean-as-cached-value - my apologies to [Andrew Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211563/andrew-marshall) who gave an otherwise completely correct answer.

Comment: This is what `nil` and the entire concept of `null` are for.

Comment: I edited my question because I hadn't done it right the first time - I also want to memoize nil.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Explicitly check if the value of `@x_query` is `nil` instead:

```
def x?
  @x_query = expensive_way_to_calculate_x if @x_query.nil?
  @x_query
end
```

Note that if this wasn't an instance variable, you would have to check if it was defined also/instead, since all instance variables default to `nil`.

Given your update that `@x_query`'s memoized value can be `nil`, you can use `defined?` instead to get around the fact that all instance variables default to `nil`:

```
def x?
  defined?(@x_query) or @x_query = expensive_way_to_calculate_x
  @x_query
end
```

Note that doing something like `a = 42 unless defined?(a)` won't work as expected since once the parser hits `a =`, `a` is defined *before* it reaches the conditional. However, this isn't true with instance variables since they default to `nil` the parser doesn't define them when it hits `=`. Regardless, I think it's a good idiom to use `or` or `unless`'s long block form instead of a one-line `unless` with `defined?` to keep it consistent.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because it is the answer to the first version of my question, but please take a look at my edits -- again, apologies.

Comment: @SeamusAbshere I've updated my answer to reflect your update `:)`.

Comment: `a = 42 unless defined?(a)` makes `a` nil, but `@a = 42 unless defined?(@a)` makes `@a` 42, so the `or` syntax isn't absolutely required in this example.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Hmm, I thought I verified it behaved the same with instance variables, but it seems you're correct. I assume it's because `@a` has a value already even though it isn't defined.

Comment: @SeamusAbshere I've updated my answer to reflect the way instance variables affect the last bit.

Answer (score 29):

To account for `nil`, use `defined?` to see if the variable has been defined:

```
def x?
  return @x_query if defined? @x_query
  @x_query = expensive_way_to_calculate_x
end
```

`defined?` will return `nil` if the variable hasn't been defined, or the string `"instance_variable"` otherwise:

```
irb(main):001:0> defined? @x
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> @x = 3
=> 3
irb(main):003:0> defined? @x
=> "instance-variable"
```