# Caching, when nil or false are acceptable results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In some ruby classes, it is useful to cache the results of an expensive operation using the `||=` operator, as in the following snippet:

```
class CacheableCalculations
  def foobar
    @foobar ||= lambda { some_expensive_calculation }.call
  end
end
```

The issue arrises when the returned value is either nil or false, as this test shows:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :counter

  def initialize(value)
    @counter = 0
    @value = value
  end

  def fancy_calculation
    @foo ||= lambda { @counter += 1; @value }.call
  end
end

first = Example.new(true)
5.times { first.fancy_calculation }
puts first.counter  # <== 1, expected

second = Example.new(false)
5.times { second.fancy_calculation }
puts second.counter  # <== 5, not caching

third = Example.new(nil)
5.times { third.fancy_calculation }
puts third.counter  # <== 5, not caching
```

Is there any pros or cons with using the `defined?` operator instead, as in the following block of code?

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :counter

  def initialize(value)
    @counter = 0
    @value = value
  end

  def fancy_calculation
    (defined? @foo) ? @foo : (@foo = lambda { @counter += 1; @value }.call)
  end
end
```

This is still one 1 line, but is quite repetitive.

Is there a better way of easily returning cached results, regardless of what the value is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158972/how-can-i-memoize-a-method-that-may-return-true-false-or-nil-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the way it is written is that the ternary operator `?:` has higher precedence than assignment `=` so it is parsed as

```
def fancy_calculation
  ((defined? @foo) ? @foo : @foo) = lambda { @counter += 1; @value }.call # NO
end
```

which you **don't** want, because `@foo` is always assigned to.

Instead, do this

```
def fancy_calculation
  defined?(@foo) ? @foo : (@foo = lambda { @counter += 1; @value }.call)
end
```

This is probably about as succinct as can be without using a separate package/function specifically for memoization.

Comment: Thanks! that was an artifact of the example, not my original question. Fixing the question

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called memoization. There used to be a method doing what you need in Rails but at some point they extracted to a separate `memoist` gem. Check it out: https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist

There is an alternative one as well: https://github.com/dkubb/memoizable