# How can I save the value of an instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, load

If I have a list of items, and for every one of them I'm calling an instance method, how can I save the value of the method and prevent it from being calculated every time it's called?

Say I have two items:

```
<% if method_true %>
  do something
<% end %>
<% if method_true %>
  do something else
<% end %>
```

If method_true == true, how can I just pass the value `true` through the two ifs instead of calculating it every time?

Comment: Are you calling `item.method_true` on every item in the list? Or is it a helper method?

Comment: @messanjah I'm using both, actually, so the questions wasn't necessarily specific to either. Why, are the two calculated differently?

Comment: It could be significant. If each item could return a different value, then you wouldn't want to save off one of them to reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more sophisticated answer out there, but for my app I just saved the value in an instance variable.

**model**

```
def method_true
  #...
end
```

**view**

```
<% if @model.method_true.true? %>
  <% @x = true %>
<% end %>
```

After that, you can use

```
<% if @x == true %>
```

instead of

```
<% if @model.method_true.true? %>
```

and the method won't have to recalculated. And if `method_true` isn't true, than `@x` will be nil, so the `if?` conditionals won't be executed.

Comment: Wow...I was expecting to have to do something super complicated involving counter caching or something, so I didn't even consider it could be this simple...thank you. I'll award bounty as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You could [memoize](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/basics-of-ruby-memoization/) `method_true?` (Ruby methods that return booleans end in question marks, by convention).

If `your expensive calculation` can only be true/false:

```
def method_true?
  if @method_true.nil?
    @method_true = # your expensive calculation
  end
  @method_true
end
```

If you also care about memoizing nil:

```
def method_true?
  unless defined?(@method_true)
    @method_true = # your expensive calculation
  end
  @method_true
end
```

[StackOverflow question on memoizing true/false/nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158972/how-can-i-memoize-a-method-that-may-return-true-false-or-nil-in-ruby)