# Can I safely tell Rails to remember the result of an expensive instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-5

My `current_user` has a `has_privilege?` method which calls the database to check whether this user has a certain admin privilege or a superceding one (system is similar to Wordpress privileges). As `has_privilege?` gets called several times per page, can I tell Rails to remember the result for as long as the instance exists, using the method explained at [How can I save the value of an instance method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613335/how-can-i-save-the-value-of-an-instance-method), or would this make the app insecure? It's a bad idea to put this information into the session variable or cache, right?

Comment: If you are using this value in view part, it's better to store instance variable in before_action or after_action and use that variable in view pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as long as the instance exists

It depends what you mean by that.

Rails treat each HTTP requests in a separated process so you can cache the `has_privilege?` method output for the current request (so calling many times the method will query the DB only the first time), but on the next request, it will be executed again and then cached (and actually you want that as you may change the permissions and don't want the user to keep the old permissions).

In order to do so you can use this simple trick:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord
  def has_privilege?
    @has_privilege ||= begin
      # You code here. The returned value will be cached in @has_privilege.
    end
  end
end
```

So the first time the method is called, `@has_privilege` is `nil` for your instance of the user, so the `||` will its right side part which is the `= begin ... end`.
Excepted if the code return `nil`, the value will be assigned to `@has_privilege`.

On the next call, `@has_privilege` is no more `nil`, therefore `||` will no trigger its right side part and return immediately.

### I need a cross request cache

In this case, you have to go with [JWT](https://jwt.io) and save the value in the token.
JWT is a token generated and signed by the server, and it must be sent back in to each requests, otherwise the server will reject it.

As only the server can sign the token, in the case the user tries to change it, the server will reject and sign out the user.

You can read more on their website, it's quite simple to use.